# Setting servername in vimrc as opposed to command line switch

Tags: vim

Is it possible to set vim's servername from my vimrc instead of using the `--servername` command line switch? If I try one of

```
set v:servername="TEX"
let v:servername="TEX"
```

I get unknown option error and cannot overwrite read-only variable error respectively.

Comment: It's also possible to use alias or something similar, see also [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178335/is-it-possible-to-specify-vim-servername-in-vimrc-or-somewhere-else-according)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**2023 update**

As pointed out by @user202729 in his answer (give him credit), it's possible to do since [8.0.0475 patch](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/7416f3e73ab2c4e7ae3adc2ff6e70234f7d40d2e) (18 March 2017) by starting Vim with `--servername=` (by default some unique name is generated) and then using `call remote_startserver('TEX')` in `vimrc`.

**Original (outdated) answer from 2012**

According to documentation (`:help v:servername`) the `v:servername` variable is read only.

And according to source code `serverRegisterName()` in `if_xcmdsrv.c` is called from three places:

- `main()` function
- X11 main window initialization
- GTK+ main window initialization

So the answer to your question is no, you can't set server name in your `.vimrc` or anywhere else except command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

For a sufficiently new of vim there's the function `remote_startserver`.

```
                    *remote_startserver()* *E941* *E942*
remote_startserver({name})
        Become the server {name}.  This fails if already running as a
        server, when |v:servername| is not empty.

        Can also be used as a |method|: >
            ServerName()->remote_startserver()
```

Available since Vim version 8.0.475. <sub>according to VimTeX documentation</sub>

So you can simply start vim with no servername and start one in vimrc.

**Note**: Vim will automatically change the servername (append 1, 2, etc.) to avoid conflict if there are multiple running Vim instances.