# Is there a way to tell instances of gvim apart without using --servername?

Tags: vim

Since my question [Setting servername in vimrc as opposed to command line switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922732/setting-servername-in-vimrc-as-opposed-to-command-line-switch) turned out not to be feasible, I am looking for help. Is there some way that I can tell apart different instances of gvim?

Scenario: I am making a lightweight realtime LaTeX plugin for vim. Currently it works as long as I only have one instance of gvim running. But, if I have two `.tex` files open in separate windows, the command I am using to get my previewer, yap, to talk to vim

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe" --remote +%l "%f
```

doesn't always talk to the correct instance of gvim running. In my previous question I was trying to use the `--servername` option to get it to talk to the correct instance, but since I am opening gvim by right clicking->open with->gvim, and since I can't set the servername at runtime, I can't get each instance of gvim to get a unique servername.

So is there some way that I could uniquely identify each instance of gvim? My last resort hack would be to use autohotkey to parse the name of the file in the window title and send the keys through autohotkey, but I feel like there should be a simpler way...

Comment: Are you looking for `v:servername`?

Comment: If you read the accepted answer in the question linked to in the first sentence, you will find that `v:servername` is read-only, and may only be set by the `--servername` switch, which this question is avoiding.

Comment: Each vim instance will set `v:servername` to something different automatically. The idea I want to put forward is have is the same as the technique used in AsysnCommand and the one mentioned in this vim wiki article: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Execute_external_programs_asynchronously_under_Windows#Getting_results_back_into_Vim

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't notice the servername was automatically unique. Now I just need some way to tell yap which servername goes with which file.

Comment: I would suggest you describe in more detail what you are doing. Is your plugin listening to specific autocmd events and then executing some shell command? If so what does this shell command look like. Or are you doing something different? Maybe some server/client architecture? Or some kind of FileSystemWatcher/inotify/FSevents file watching scheme? With out more information all I can suggest is you look into `:h clientserver`.

Comment: The problem is not vim talking to yap. The problem is yap talking to vim. All yap can do is call one command and use the `%l` (line number) and `%f` (fully qualified filename) macros. As shown above I use it to call gvim.exe. But I don't know of any way to get yap to associate a servername with a filename.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15444/discussion-between-peter-rincker-and-nulluser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every launched Vim instance will automatically have a unique `v:servername`; on Windows, I get `GVIM`, `GVIM1`, `GVIM2`, ...

<sub>(Already mentioned by Peter Rincker in the comments.)</sub>