# is it possible to specify vim servername in .vimrc, or somewhere else, according to filetype?

Tags: vim, file-type, server-name

I have to type

```
gvim --servername xdvi toto.tex
```

to enable inverse search from xdvi to latex.

Is there a way to encapsulate this in `.vimrc`: when vim detects the .tex file, an autocmd sets the servername to vimrc ? It seems it is too late once vim is launched, or?

If not in `.vimrc`, where ?

Comment: `xdvi` is the name you give to your Vim instance. What does it have to do with xdvi and/or latex and/or inverse search?

Comment: Because .Xdefaults or .Xresources contains a line like
xdvi.editor: gvim --servername xdvi --remote +%l %f
that directs xdvi to the right instance of gvim.

Comment: Vote to move to Vim StackExchange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting servername in vimrc as opposed to command line switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922732/setting-servername-in-vimrc-as-opposed-to-command-line-switch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special `v:servername` variable is read-only; you cannot change it from within Vim. If you need a certain servername, that has to be specified on startup via the `--servername` argument.

To avoid the additional typing, I would suggest a special shell alias (on Unix) or small batch wrapper (on Windows). Depending on how crucial this is, you could even add some scripting logic to check for `.tex` arguments, and only then set the servername.

The only way to achieve this from within Vim would be forking a new instance of Vim (via `system()`), passing all arguments plus the servername argument, and then closing the original Vim instance via `:quit`. But that's very cumbersome and not as simple to implement.

Comment: General remark: whatever the method is, the servername might not be the same (vim may append some number if there's a conflict). [Source](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1576#issuecomment-579770809)

Comment: @user202729 Right, that's why the answer instructs to pass a custom one via `--servername`, assuming you either choose something unique like a UUID, or dealing with the potential existing name (e.g. by querying existing servernames first).